# PLSQL Printing prime numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to print prime numbers between `1 to 50`. But I don't understand what I am doing wrong in my code. After `BEGIN`, SQLDeveloper says I had an error because it expected another sign and not `=` .

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    i NUMBER;
    counter NUMBER;
    n NUMBER;
    k NUMBER;
BEGIN
    i := 2;
    counter := 0;
    n := 50;
    k := n/2;
    FOR i IN 1..k LOOP
        IF (n%i := 0 ) THEN
            counter := 1;
        END IF;
        IF (counter := 0) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n||' is prime number');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    i NUMBER;
    counter NUMBER;
    n NUMBER;
    k NUMBER;
BEGIN
    i := 2;
    counter := 0;
    n := 50;
    k := floor(n/2);
    FOR i IN 1..k LOOP
        IF (mod(n, i) = 0 ) THEN
            counter := 1;
        END IF;
        IF (counter = 0) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n||' is prime number');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

`k := n/2;` -- added FLOOR (k is NUMBER, by default it's NUMBER(38, max_scale))

`IF (n%i := 0 ) THEN` -> `IF (mod(n, i) = 0 ) THEN`

Oracle has MOD function for remainder + to compare you need to use `=`,

`:=` is for assignment.

```
DECLARE
    counter NUMBER;
    k NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR n IN 1..50 LOOP   
    counter := 0;
    k := floor(n/2);
    FOR i IN 2..k LOOP
        IF (mod(n, i) = 0 ) THEN
            counter := 1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    IF (counter = 0) THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(n||' is prime number');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but how can I print each prime number when executing the block?

Comment: @Ryuuko Matoi You have some logical errors in your code. I've added the other version

Answer (score 0):

In your IF clause you are assigning the value instead of comparison. You are using := operator, where you shd be using =

It shud be like (IF counter = 0) then
......

Also I dont think n%i would work, you could do IF (trunc(n) = n) then ... or IF (mod (n,i) =0) then ...

Answer (score 0):

```
       --this function is check prime number.
       create or replace function prime_a(x number) return
       varchar2 is
       n integer;
       ans varchar2(50);
       begin
       n:=(x/2);
       for i in 2..n loop 
       if mod(x,i)=0
       then ans:='not a prime';
       exit;
       else ans:='prime';
       end if;
       end loop;
       return ans;
       end;
       /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 step-1:
  create table tob(prime number);
 step-2:
 create or replace procedure ro(m number,n number) 
 is
 a integer;
 co Boolean;
 begin
 for j in m..n loop
 co:=false;
 co:=(j=1 );
 a:=(j/2);
 for i in 2..a loop 
 co:=(mod(j,i)=0);
 exit when co;
 end loop;
 if(not co) then
 insert into tob values(J);
 end if;
 end loop;
 commit;
 end;
 /
 step-3:
   exec ro(1,50);

 step-4: check:-
 select * from tob;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create or replace in your source code:

```
 function prime_a(x number) return
   varchar2 is
   n integer;
   ans varchar2(50);
   begin
   n:=(x/2);
   for i in 2..n loop 
   if mod(x,i)=0
   then ans:='not a prime';
   exit;
   else ans:='prime';
   end if;
   end loop;
   return ans;
   end;
   /
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just check for previous prime divisibility?

```
create table prime (primeno bigint)
declare @counter bigint
set @counter = 2
while @counter < 1000000
begin
if not exists(select top 1 primeno from prime where @counter % primeno = 0)
   insert into prime select @counter
set @counter = @counter + 1
end

select * from prime order by 1
```

You could certainly cap the numbers you are checking against in the where condition to reduce your overheads further.

Answer (score -1):

```
declare
  i number;
  j number;
  k number:=0;
begin 
  for i in 1..50 
  loop
    for j in 2..i-1
    loop
      if mod(i,j)=0 then
        k:=1;
        exit;
      end if;
    end loop;
    if k=0 then
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
    end if;
    k:=0;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare
  y number := 0;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 50 loop
    for x in 1 .. i loop
      if mod(i, x) = 0 then
        y := y + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    if y <= 2 then
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
    end if;
    y := 0;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Comment: This seems to be the exact same solution as in the provided answers, except that it is less efficient (number of possible divisors goes up to n instead of n/2)

Answer (score -3):

```
   create or replace function prime_a(x number) return varchar2 is
     n integer;
     ans varchar2(50);
   begin
     n:=(x/2);
     for i in 2..n loop 
       if mod(x,i)=0 then 
          ans:='not a prime';
          exit;
       else 
          ans:='prime';
       end if;
     end loop;
     return ans;
   end;
   /
```

Comment: why? its not justify prime number? please ans me?

Comment: It does, but question was "print prime numbers between 1 to 50".